# How can I tell if a particular heuristic is admissible, and why mine is not?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, path-finding, heuristics, pacman

The definition of an admissible heuristic is one that "does not overestimate the path of a particular goal".
I am attempting to write a Pac-Man heuristic for finding the fastest method to eat dots, some of which are randomly scattered across the grid. However it is failing my admissibility test.
Here are the steps of my algorithm:

```
sum = 0, list = grid.getListofDots()
1. Find nearest dot from starting position (or previous dot that was removed) using manhattan distance
2. add to sum
3. Remove dot from list of possible dots
4. repeat steps 1 - 3 until list is empty
5. return the sum
```

Since I'm using manhattan distance, shouldn't this be admissible? If not, are there any suggestions or other approaches to make this algorithm admissible?

Comment: you consider the distance from where you are, but moving changes all the distances.

Comment: But if I use the manhattan distance of the dot I just went to, wouldn't that make certain that it is still admissable?

Comment: you consider some distances twice. consider this : `*___*C_*` (there are 3 spaces). Pacman is `C`, `*` are the dots, `_` is an empty space. your algorithm counts 11. (left, right, left). The best value is 9 (go right first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302445/how-can-i-tell-if-a-particular-heuristic-is-admissible-and-why-mine-is-not#comment65939157_39302445) your heuristics isn't admissible. Another example is:

[image: Pacman heuristics]

Your cost is 9 but the best path has cost 6.

---

A very, very simple admissible heuristics is:

```
number_of_remaining_dots
```

but it isn't very tight. A small improvement is:

```
manhattan_distance_to_nearest_dot + dots_left_out
```

Other possibilities are:

```
distance_to_nearest_dot   // Found via Breadth-first search
```

or

```
manhattan_distance_to_farthest_dot
```